# How to find n-th element of Fibonacci sequence in assembly using stack and recursion

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, stack, fibonacci

I am trying to write classical fib(n) function in assembly *(intel x86)* that is returning a n-th element of Fibonacci sequence.

I have written iterative version quite easily, but I'm having trouble trying to manipulate with recursion. This is what I tried:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.text

# unsigned fib(unsigned)
.globl fib

fib_n:
    enter 0, 0

    mov eax, 0

    # n = 0 or n = 1
    cmp edi, 1
    jbe end

    mov eax, 1

    # n == 2
    cmp edi, 2
    je end

    # n > 2, entering recursion

    # fib(n-1)
    push rdi
    dec edi

    call fib_n
    mov r8d, eax 

    pop rdi

    # fib(n-2)
    push rdi
    sub edi, 2

    call fib_n
    mov r9d, eax

    pop rdi

    # fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    mov eax, r8d
    add eax, r9d

end:
    leave
    ret
```

I am expecting for calls marked *#fib(n-1)* and *#fib(n-1)* to store **local eax** results in r8d and r9d registers, and then just add them and return through eax, but this is what I get as output:

n = 1 (1st el): 0 (works fine) 
n = 2: 1 (works fine) 
n = 3: 1 (works fine)

(wrong results) 
n = 4: 2 
n = 5: 2

n = 6: 3 
n = 7: 3 
...

I also tried pushing rax to the stack as well as rdi, but I still get wrong results. What am I missing?

Comment: Note this can take quite a while for large values of n, as the total number of calls will be 2*fib(n)-1. The max value for 32 bit unsigned integers is fib(47) = 2971215073, so the number of calls will be 5942430145 (5.94 billion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Register `r8d` is not preserved across recursive calls.

You don't need `enter` nor `leave`. No parameters were pushed.
It's easier to preserve the index `rdi` at the entry of *fib_n*.

```
fib_n:
    push    rdi
    xor     eax, eax
    cmp     edi, 2
    jb      end            ; fib(1) = 0
    mov     eax, 1
    je      end            ; fib(2) = 1
    dec     edi
    call    fib_n          ; -> EAX
    push    rax            ; (1) Preserve intermediate result!
    dec     edi    
    call    fib_n          ; -> EAX
    add     eax, [rsp]     ; fib(n) = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    add     rsp, 8         ; (1)
end:
    pop     rdi
    ret
```

**EDIT**

The below version of the code incorporates comments made by [rcgldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382344/how-to-find-n-th-element-of-fibonacci-sequence-in-assembly-using-stack-and-recur/56383784?noredirect=1#comment99369146_56383784) and [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382344/how-to-find-n-th-element-of-fibonacci-sequence-in-assembly-using-stack-and-recur/56383784?noredirect=1#comment99373080_56383784).
This code now removes 5 base-cases and is much cleaner.

```
fib_n:
    cmp     edi, 5         ; n
    jb      .LT5           ; Base-cases
    push    rdi            ; (1) Preserve n
    dec     edi            ; n-1
    call    fib_n          ; -> EAX
    push    rax            ; (2) Preserve intermediate result!
    dec     edi            ; n-2
    call    fib_n          ; -> EAX
    pop     rdi            ; (2) Restore intermediate result
    add     eax, edi       ; fib(n) = fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
    pop     rdi            ; (1) Restore n
    ret
.LT5:
    mov     eax, edi       ; n < 5
    cmp     edi, 2
    cmc
    sbb     eax, 0         ; fib(0) = 0, fib(1) = 1
    ret                    ; fib(2) = 1, fib(3) = 2, fib(4) = 3
```

Comment: I understand my mistake. But, I don't understand last two lines of your code:
   add eax, [rsp]
   add rsp, 8
In eax there is already result of fib(n-2), but where did I use saved fib(n-1) value that was pushed to the stack (i. e. I don't understand how **rsp** points that value). Also, why is it needed to remove 8 bytes instead 4 when function has only one parameter used by **rdi** register?

Comment: Edit: I am trying to understand how the stack looks like at the moment of instruction: **add rsp, 8**. I guess [rsp] = rax (since rax was last pushed to the stack), [rsp + 4] = rdi (this will be popped explicitly in the end label), but what is at the [rsp + 8] address and how does this menage recursion?

Comment: In math, fib(0) = 0, fib(1) = 1, fib(2) = 1, fib(3) = 2, fib(4) = 3, ... .

Comment: @alexein777 `push rax` stores **8** bytes on the stack. It's the result of fib(n-1). Once fib(n-2) is in `eax`, I can add the lowest 4 bytes that are on the stack to obtain fib(n). Hereafter I need to remove the whole **8** bytes to balance the stack.

Comment: @alexein777 `[rsp]=rax`, `[rsp+8]=rdi`, [rsp+16]=return address` 64-bit uses **8** byte pushes! The 1st is removed with `add rsp,8`, the 2nd is removed with `pop rdi`, and the 3rd is removed with `ret`.

Comment: @rcgldr: good catch.  So instead of xor-zeroing EAX, do `mov eax, edi` for `return n  if  (n<2)`.  But probably still worth another `je` to take `fib(2)` as another base-case that returns `1` instead of `n`, because that cuts off 2 more `call`s.

Comment: @SepRoland Thanks for clarification, I understand well now. Just one another question: would **pop rax** instead **add rsp, 8** have the same effect?

Comment: @alexein777 Using `pop rax` would certainly raise `rsp` by 8, **but it would also destroys the result that we had ready in the `EAX` register!** For another and cleaner way to code this problem, see my edited answer.